# jQuery onClick() Sound Effect and Redirection in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, audio, embed

So, against both mine and the bosses advice, a client insists that that want a 'boing' sound effect on all of the links on their websites main navigation when they click them before the link actually takes the suer to a new page.

To do this I am using jQuery to append an `embed` tag to the body when the link is clicked before sending the user to the new page. Here's the jQuery I am using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function($) {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#menu_container a").click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var url = $(this).attr('href');

                $('body').append('<embed src="/media/sounds/boing_spring.mp3" autostart="true" width="1" height="1" id="LegacySound" enablejavascript="true">');

                setTimeout(function() {
                    window.location = url;
                }, 500);

                setTimeout();
            });
        });
    })(jQuery)
</script>
```

So, this seems to work Ok in Safari/Chrome/FF/Opera on OSX/Ubuntu and Windows.

But, when it comes to Internet Explorer is works fine on my WinXP machine with IE8, but the sounds doesn't work on the bosses Win7 machine running IE9. So, what could the cause of this be?  Is it jsut IE being IE, or is it me screwing up?

Comment: Does it work in IE8 mode? Can his computer make other sounds?

Comment: No, it doesn't work in IE8 mode; yes it can make other sounds.

Comment: In Tools menu choose "Internet Options". Open "Advanced" tab, in "Multimedia" field there is an option for disabling/enabling sounds from WWW pages.

Comment: Just got him the check, sounds are enabled.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved by adding another line like the one beow, but linking to a wma sound instead

```
$('body').append('<embed src="/media/sounds/boing_spring.mp3" autostart="true" width="1" height="1" id="LegacySound" enablejavascript="true">');
```

Comment: I want to load a sound and play it several times (sound of firing a gun) that each time the gun is fired the sound must be played. what should i do?